# Script keeps running when using psycopg2 to connect to Postgres Database on windows

Tags: python, postgresql

```py
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
                                  password = "postgres",
                                  host = "127.0.0.1",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  dbname = "postgres")

  
print("You are connected ")
```

I have tried connecting to the Postgres database using python, but when I run this scripts it just keeps running without returning any error. any help please, can't figure out what am doing wrong, I have tried searching the previous answers with no result. but am able to connect via psql or the web interface, but not using psycopg2 with python.

Comment: Did it print "You are connected"?  What is the longest you have waited for it to do anything?  Have you tried connecting with something else, like `psql`?

Comment: more than an hour

Comment: Define keeps running? How are you running the script?